# How to prevent a bug to spread through future new features

Tags: git, git-flow

We are facing a problem implementing Git as our version control.  As soon as possible we want to implement full [Git Flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

Lets imagine this situation ( Branches: Develop & Master ):

- Maria is working on a new feature and at the end of the day she pushes it to Develop branch.
- Next day Bob will `pull` all the changes made into `Develop` and start to work on a NEW feature.
- At the end of the day, Bob also pushes his changes to `Develop`.

BUT, after that they discover that Maria's first push had a bug and they can't push it to production (Master). So Bob's code is now "infected" with Maria's Bug.

How to solve this or even prevent this kind of thing ?

Comment: I'm not sure that there is any way to prevent this (aside from writing bug-free code).  However the typical way to handle this is after the bug is discovered is to fix the bug in a `Hotfix` branch, and then merge `Hotfix` into both `Develop` and `Master`.

Comment: @0x5453 this is wrong. The bug doesn't exist on master, merging the hotfix in there would break things further. The fix is to simply fix `develop` and move on.

Comment: @meagar You're right.  Replace `Develop` -> `Bob's feature branch` and `Master` -> `Develop` in my comment.

Comment: Bob's feature branch is gone, it's already merged. There is only `develop`, and only `develop` requires a fix. There is no need to overcomplicate this by talking about merging fixes into multiple branches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're thinking about version control all wrong. Nothing was "infected", a bug simply existed on `develop`, prior to it being shipped to production.  Bugs don't "spread through future releases", they simply exist until you fix them.

Either create a fix and merge it into `develop`, *or* create a `revert` for Maria's merge, and merge that into `develop`. Either way, the fix is to simply fix `develop` and move on. "Bob's code" didn't become "infected", the develop branch was just held up (hopefully briefly) by a bug.

You can't *prevent* this kind of thing. Bugs will appear in code, this is a fact of life. You just happened to catch the bug before it was shipped, this is a *good* thing, it's Git behaving as intended. You simply write a fix, add a regression test and move on.

If you're following Git Flow, this is even less of a problem: Both Maria and Bob's work would go into a release, which would undergo a round of testing and bug fixing before being shipped. If you intended to merge Bob's changes directly into `master`, and it's a problem that they're held up by waiting for a solid release branch, then they should have been considered a Hotfix from the very beginning.

Comment: Hi ! So after some of our team pull a bug from develop and start working on new things (that may be related to the bug or not). The best approach would be sending a `Hotfix` and eveyrone just make a pull of it ?

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro No, definitely not. You just fix the bug on `develop` and nobody else needs to do anything. The only time another person needs to even be aware that a bug happened is when it impacts the work they're doing on their own feature, in which case they either need to wait until the bug is fixed and then pull the changes into their feature by either rebasing it or merging from `develop` into their feature. You never merge a hotfix into anywhere except `develop` and `master`, a `hotfix` is not relevant here.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro Just follow [the docs](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). It's very clear on what is allowed to be merged into what, and when.

Comment: @meager Ok, but tell me this. I push my code with a bug, everyone from my team pulls that and work on their own features. I find the bug, fix it and push it. Later that day someone will push the his/her code with the bug, because they didn't pull the fix and it will overwrite my fix.  
So the pull wouldn't be mandatory ?

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro No, that isn't how Git works, you're completely misunderstanding this. The bug stays fixed even if people merge code on top of it, unless they have a merge conflict and they *specifically* resolve the conflict by destroying your changes, *and* removing the regression tests you introduced.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro I suggest you run some very simple experiments to prove to yourself how VCS works, not just Git but *all* VCS. None of them suffer from the problem you're imagining here. Just because a branch was forked from an earlier point in time doesn't mean that **all newer change is obliterated** when you merge it back in, which is what you're implying by worrying about bugs coming back.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro Also ask yourself; If bugs coming back were a problem every time somebody merged a feature request into `develop`, don't you think Git Flow would address this?